# pass an object out of a JSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

A global ld object is used throughout my program. It's contents can be entered manually, picked up from a server, or read from local storage. The writeload() function uses the ld object, and when the object is picked up from local storage, all is well. I had hoped that the JSON call would use the global storage ld, but it apparently doesn't. Thus my question is: how to I get the JSON ld object to the global ld object. I'm pretty sure I could perform the writeload() function by duplicating its code inside the JSON call, but it's long and I'd like to avoid that if possible. All suggestions are welcome as well as any thoughts on a better structure/way of doing things. Many thanks.

```
switch (oSource.from) {
    case 'server':
        $.getJSON('reports/' + oSource.filename,function(ld) {
            writeload();
        });
        break;
    case 'local':
        ld=$.jStorage.get(oSource.filename);
        writeload();
        break;
}
```

Comment: I hope I understand the question. If my comment suggests otherwise, please clarify. The ld parameter in your function is what the server should return. it is not your global variable that you are trying to use.

Comment: @akonsu What I hoped for was that the JSON call would fill the global ld, but it doesn't. What I need to do is get the contents of the ld parameter to the contents of the global ld. I know the JSON is working correctly, because I can successfully look at its contents within the JSON call, but how do I copy the contents of the JSON ld to the global ld. At the point of the JSON call, the global ld is empty of meaningful data. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
$.getJSON('reports/' + oSource.filename, function(new_ld) {
    ld = new_ld;
    writeload();
});
```

when you send a request to your URL ('reports/' + oSource.filename), it returns an object, and jQuery that you are using calls your function with this object as a parameter. the parameter is called new_ld inside the function invocation, so you just assign it to your global variable. In your original post, you had your function parameter named 'ld' and it effectively hid the global variable with the same name from the scope of the function.

Comment: My wife just called me and is insisting I come to bed (past midnight here -- Oregon is the US). I'll give it a try first thing in the morning. I don't offhand understand it as I'm a newbie, but I will study it until I do. Thanks.

Comment: Works! Many thanks. I should have thought of that, but obviously didn't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see parameter in handler function is hiding global variable.
You can try that:

```
switch (oSource.from) {
    case 'server':
        $.getJSON('reports/' + oSource.filename, function (response) {
        ld = response;
        writeload();
        });
    ...
```